# What does the prefix in dates mean?

Tags: bronze-age

While reading history text online, I find that some dates have a prefix e.g.

- c. 5000 BP
- c. 3300 BCE
- ca. 3300 BC

What does the prefix mean?

Comment: might be a better fit on english.se

Comment: @jwenting I disagree. It is relevant to this site, however simple.

Comment: @called2voyage the term is relevant, the explanation of it off topic.

Comment: On second thought, it is general reference even though I would consider it on topic otherwise.

Comment: As the person asking this question, both the prefix (c. ca.) and postfix (BP, BC, BCE) did not look like words to me. It is similar to the "$" in $2500. Furthermore, some (Wikipedia) say "Circa is widely used in **genealogy** and **historical** writing". So I feel this should be more on-topic than not.

Comment: I also realised that I somehow Googled the wrong terms and keep getting chartered accountants and California instead. Now that I know what it means, I do get the correct search results every time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

c or ca means circa, which means approximately.

Comment: It means ‘around’.